# When defining a model, can a method be triggered for a column's value on insertion into that table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Take the following model:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(VARCHAR(255))
```

I want to call a method that enforces all characters in `Thing.data` to be lowercase (think: `str.lower`), and achieving that similar to the following would be preferable:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(VARCHAR(255), on_insertion=lambda s: s.lower())
```

I believe a viable alternative would be the following, however I was hoping for something more idiomatic:

```
class Thing(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(VARCHAR(255))

    def __init__(self, id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.data = data.lower()
```

Comment: Do you actually need it to happen *on insertion*? Your second example does it on instance creation, not technically insertion. Usually the way to do transformations like this is to use [`validates`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#sqlalchemy.orm.validates), but that happens on attribute assignment, not on insertion. If you actually need it to always happen on insertion, you'll need to use the [`before_insertion`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert) event.

Comment: You could also use a plain old [property descriptor, or a hybrid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#using-descriptors-and-hybrids), and lower case all incoming strings in the setter.

Comment: @univerio seems to have answered my question with his comment, as he confirmed the above method should work, but a more idiomatic solution would be [validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators). I do not have the strict requirement for the method to be called immediately before insertion. I would accept your comment as an answer if possible!